# How to dynamically create and manage new controllers in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-3.5, url-rewriting

From a private area of my site developed in ASP.NET MVC  I want to create new pages (or more properly Controllers) with a URL segment like "www.mysite.com/newpage/" (and not "www.mysite.com/mycontroller/newpage/");

I don't want create controllers at design/development time, I want be able to create controllers at runtime and store their names (the url segment) in a database, so when a page is requested, the application checks if it exists in the database and render the page (the view).

Anyone knows an example on Internet that explain the best method to implement an option like that?

Comment: Which version? I deleted 3.5 as there is no such version.

Comment: MVC version 3, sorry I confused with .net framework 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible solution to do this would be create multiple routes for a single controller and do the code according to the route name. These route name can be managed by database as well.

**Example :**

*Global.asax*

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // The collection of route can be manage via DB
    foreach (string route in new[] { "route1", "route2", "route3" })
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
                route,
                route + "/{*args}",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction", args = UrlParameter.Optional, routeName = route }
        );
    }
}
```

*MyController*

```
public ActionRestult MyAction(string args)
{
    switch(RouteData.Values["routeName"].ToString()){
        case "route1" :
            // do your code
        break;
        case "route2" :
            // do your code
        break;
        case "route3" :
            // do your code
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help !!